# Robustness (прочность) в Java

Tags: java

Добрый день! Недавно попалась весьма интересная задачка на Java. Которой хотел бы поделиться.

Дан следующий класс

```
public class RobustCheck {

    private final char first;
    private final char second;

    public RobustCheck(char first, char second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public boolean equals (RobustCheck b) {
        return this.first == b.first && this.second == b.second;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return 31 * first + second;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<RobustCheck> s = new HashSet<RobustCheck>();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            for(char ch='a'; ch<='z'; ch++) {
                s.add(new RobustCheck(ch, ch));
            }
        System.out.println(s.size());
    }
}
```

И вопросы:

1. Почему программа возвращает размер 260 вместо 26? Как ее исправить?
2. Чего не хватает в данной программе, чтобы она указала ошибку на этапе компиляции?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отмечайте такие **действительно интересные** вопросы, как *учебное-задание*.

И такой вопросик. Как думаете robustness в данном контексте это ирония ? Может лучше robustless (знаю, что слово малоупотребимое)?

Comment: @avp, просто взято из лекций по IT-Security из раздела Robust programming и не придумал я лучшего слова.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Задача на знание краеугольных камней языка Java и недостатков в его дизайне. В данном случае метод `RobustCheck#equals` *перегружает* (`overloading`) метод `Object#equals`, в результате чего при сравнении объектов `RobustCheck` используется метод `Object#equals`, который вместо сравнения на *эквивалентность* сравнивает на *идентичность*. Все 260 созданных в программе объектов `RobustCheck` не являются идентичными, т.к. физически являются отдельными объектами, размещенными в своих собственных областях памяти. Поэтому методы `HashSet` "считают" их неравными друг другу и добавляют во множество. В то время как логически неравных объектов `RobustCheck` только 26 штук, все последующие эквивалентны одному из этих 26-ти. Поэтому нам же необходимо *перекрыть* (`overriding`) метод `Object#equals`, чтобы изменить семантику сравнения. Для этого сигнатура метода `RobustCheck#equals` должна соответствовать сигнатуре перекрываемого `Object#equals`; перепишем метод так:

```
public boolean equals (Object b) {
    if (b instanceof RobustCheck)
        return this.first == ((RobustCheck)b).first && this.second == ((RobustCheck)b).second;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Чтобы такие ошибки (когда вместо перекрытия мы по ошибке используем перегрузку) смог заметить компилятор, сообщим ему наши намерения о том, что метод `Object#equals` мы перекрываем в производном классе `RobustCheck`, добавив соответствующую аннотацию:

```
@Override
public boolean equals (Object b) {
    if (b instanceof RobustCheck)
        return this.first == ((RobustCheck)b).first && this.second == ((RobustCheck)b).second;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Ну вот теперь все должно работать как надо:

```
>java RobustCheck
26
```

К сожалению, это не исправляет недостатки в дизайне Java. Более интересный вопрос, в дополнение к этой задачке, заключается в том, как вообще избежать всей этой "мумба-юмбы" при определении семантики сравнения двух объектов? В случае с Java ответа, к сожалению, нет. Но можно использовать более продуманные языки. К примеру, [Scala](http://scala-lang.org/), которая самостоятельно определяет корректную семантику сравнения на эквивалентность для *неизменяемых* (*immutable*) объектов, избавляя программиста от этой чреватой ошибками задачи:

```
object Main extends App {
    // Неизменяемые объекты моделируются в Scala с помощью специальных
    // "case"-классов.
    case class RobustCheck(first: Char, second: Char)

    val s = collection.mutable.HashSet.empty[RobustCheck]

    for (i <- 1 to 10)
        for (c <- 'a' to 'z')
            s += RobustCheck(c, c)

    println(s.size)
}
```

Результат ожидаем:

```
>scala Main
26
```

Без всяких заморочек.

Comment: @avp, очень рад, что ответ помог вам понять что-то новое :)
@Dex, выкладывайте, уверен, такие задачки полезны для многих изучающих Java.

Answer (score 8):

Занятно. Правильный ответ подразумевает изменение типа параметра и добавление собачки? :)

UPD. Ах да, еще каст дополнительно будет нужен.

**--- spoiler alert ---**

В общем, результат в 26 предполагается из-за того, что `Set` должен содержать только уникальные значения. Для этого переопределяется метод `equals()`, который, по задумке, должен был бы возвращать `true` для объектов, у которых одинаковые поля `first` и `second`. Фишка же в том, что `equals()` на самом деле не переопределен - оригинальная сигнатура выглядит как `equals(Object o)` (1). А `Object#equals()` выдает `true` только для идентичных объектов (`this == obj`) - вот и выходит 260. И программист заметил бы это, если бы использовал аннотацию `@Override` перед своим методом `equals()` (2).

P.S. Подобные маневры становятся особенно хорошо заметны, когда готовишься к сдаче SCJP :)

Comment: А вы попробуйте, да еще бы пару пояснений:)

Comment: Имхо, правиольный ответ подразмевает только добавление аннотации. Все остальное - это уже следствие.

Comment: Нет, в данном случае аннотация не поможет, так как сигнатуры разные.

Comment: @yozh, вот, собственно, я на этом попался, когда первый раз увидел сей код и задачу, не имея компилятора под рукой. Пришлось подтягивать знания в области. Думаю сделать задачу общей, как считаете?

Comment: Честно говоря, не знаком с критериями отметки задач в качестве "общих", так что не могу ничего посоветовать.

Comment: Аннотация четко помогает обнаружить ошибку на этапе компиляции. В этом состоит суть вопроса 2. Именно отсуствие аннотации дает возможность некорректно определить переопределяемый метод.

Answer (score 8):

Метод `equals` не переопределяет `Object.equals(Object obj)`.

Ответы:

1. При одинаковых хэшкодах для каждого 10-ка инстансов имеем разные результаты вызова `equals(Object obj)`, поэтому с точки зрения `HashSet` мы имеем неэквивалентные инстансы. (в `equals(RobustCheck b)` мы не попадаем).
2. Аннториуем метод `equals` c помощью `@Override`.

Answer (score 2):

Никогда не любил такие задачки, не умею думать =( Но тут вроде бы очевидно: 260, потому что:

> 26 букв х 10 раз  = будет 260

Не хватает ошибок?))

Comment: Не очевидно! Зря вы не любите такие задачки. Ваши программы будут жрать много памяти как минимум. Вы решаете задачу за 260 байт, а я за 26, десятикратная выгода, не находите?

Comment: Почему не очевидно, когда там вложеный цикл на 26 букв, а поверх его цикл на 10 итераций? В чем подвох?)

Comment: Ладно, я понял, просто сразу видно было, как работает переопределение и не видел ошибки в работе.